# Custom double click event on table

Tags: vaadin, cuba-platform

I have a customer table. I don't want to get the edit screen by double clicking on the item.

How could I change the default double-click action on the table?

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy, just use `event.isDoubleClick()` like this:

```
table.addListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {

    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        if (event.isDoubleClick()) {
            // The item was double-clicked, event.getItem() returns the target.
        }
    }
});
```

Source: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/119309/119308

Comment: For vaadin table it is rigth. But for the cuba-table, there isn't a addListener Method.

Comment: maybe in older vaadin version it is addItemClickListener()

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.2/gui_Table.html) you can define action for the double-click event, by using the `Table#setItemClickAction` method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Vaadin 8 table:

```
grid.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener<MyType>() {
    @Override
    public void itemClick(Grid.ItemClick<MyType> event) {
    if (event.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick()) {
        ...
```